# swift: adding address to contacts on macOS

Tags: swift, macos

Apple itself offers a nice piece of code for adding own addresses to "Contacts"-App. (see documentation for "Contacts" - Listing 1 Creating a contact)

I try to use this code. But when executing this, my app crashes with error on saving the data. (see image)

[image: error when saving data to contacts]

My code so far:

```
import AppKit
import Contacts

class ContactsClass {
    func addToContacts(
        lastName: String,
        firstName: String,
        birthDate: Date?,
        mail: String = "",
        phone1: String = "",
        phone2: String = "",
        mobile: String = "",
        street: String,
        city: String,
        postCode: String
    ) {
        // Create a mutable object to add to the contact
        let contact = CNMutableContact()
            
        contact.givenName = firstName
        contact.familyName = lastName
        
        if mail != "" {
            let homeEmail = CNLabeledValue(label: CNLabelHome, value: mail as NSString)
            contact.emailAddresses = [homeEmail]
        }
        
        contact.phoneNumbers = []
        if phone1 != "" {
            contact.phoneNumbers.append(CNLabeledValue(label: CNLabelPhoneNumberMain, value: CNPhoneNumber(stringValue: phone1)))
        }
        if phone2 != "" {
            contact.phoneNumbers.append(CNLabeledValue(label: CNLabelPhoneNumberMain, value: CNPhoneNumber(stringValue: phone2)))
        }
        if mobile != "" {
            contact.phoneNumbers.append(CNLabeledValue(label: CNLabelPhoneNumberMobile, value: CNPhoneNumber(stringValue: mobile)))
        }
        
        let homeAddress = CNMutablePostalAddress()
        homeAddress.street = street
        homeAddress.city = city
        homeAddress.postalCode = postCode
        contact.postalAddresses = [CNLabeledValue(label: CNLabelHome, value: homeAddress)]
        
        
        if birthDate != nil {
            let calendar = Calendar.current
            let dateComponents = calendar.dateComponents([.year,.month,.day], from: birthDate!)
            
            var birthday = DateComponents()
            birthday.day = dateComponents.day
            birthday.month = dateComponents.month
            birthday.year = dateComponents.year  // (Optional) Omit the year value for a yearless birthday
            contact.birthday = birthday
        }
        // Save the newly created contact
        let store = CNContactStore()
        let saveRequest = CNSaveRequest()
        saveRequest.add(contact, toContainerWithIdentifier: nil)
        do {
            try store.execute(saveRequest)
        } catch {
            print("Saving contact failed, error: \(error)")
            // Handle the error
        }
    }
}
```

Console errors are:

```
2022-10-28 06:26:03.473439+0200 justCare[11808:992463] [api] Attempt to write notes by a pre-Fall-2022 app
2022-10-28 06:26:03.499714+0200 justCare[11808:992463] [plugin] CDX_AB_GetGroupCollectionPath: nil group
2022-10-28 06:26:03.499770+0200 justCare[11808:992463] [plugin] CDX_AB_GetGroupCollectionPath: nil group
2022-10-28 06:26:03.500823+0200 justCare[11808:992463] [ABCDContact] An ABCDRecord is being saved without having a container assignment. Assigning the contact to <CNCDContainer 0x600001f9bba0 ab>. Please remember to assign contacts to containers to avoid recurring container lookup and contact re-validation costs.
```

Access to Contatcs is granted. Sandboxing is properly set for Contacts. So why this error now?

Environment:

- macOS Ventura
- XCODE 14.0.1

Comment: Sad fun fact: adding the demo-code presented by Apple Docs into an iOS app, everything is fine. Why on earth does everybody (including Apple) only offer iOS demo code and not for macOS? And why is iOS so different in details from macOS? It's just so tiresome to keep looking for the macOS equivalent. Can somebody give some help, please.

Comment: Could it be a problem with Ventura? The first line of console info seems to confirm this suspicion. `Attempt to write notes by a pre-Fall-2022 app`